# T-SQL Full Outer Join (sample provided)

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have some issues getting a full outer join to work in T-SQL. The left outer join part seems to be working okay, but the right outer join doesn't work as expected. Here's some sample data to test this on:

I have a table A with the following columns and data. The row marked with red is the row that cannot be found in table B.

[image: Table A]

And a second table B with the following columns and data. The rows marked with yellow are the rows that cannot be found in table A.

[image: Table B]

I am trying to join the tables using the following sql code:

```
select tableA.klientnr, tableA.uttakstype, tableA.uttaksnr, tableA.vareanr TableAItem,tableB.vareanr tableBitem, tableA.kvantum tableAquantity, tableB.totkvant tableBquantity 
from tableA as tableA
full outer join tableB as tableB on tableA.klientnr=tableB.klientnr and tableA.uttakstype=tableB.uttakstype and tableA.uttaksnr=tableB.uttaksnr and tableA.vareanr=tableB.vareanr and tableB.IsDeleted=0
where tableA.UttaksNr=639779 and tableA.IsDeleted=0
```

The result of the sql is the following image. The row marked in red is the extra row from tableA that does show up, but I can't get the rows from table B to show up 
[image: Result]

Expected to have 2 extra rows

```
550   SA   639779  NULL  100059  NULL  0
550   SA   639779  NULL  103040  NULL  14
```

Later edit:
Would this be correct way to handle the full outer join where there's the header/line type of structure? Or can the query be optimized?

```
SELECT ISNULL(q1.accountid, q2.accountid) AccountId
       ,ISNULL(q1.klientnr, q2.klientnr) KlientNr
       ,ISNULL(q1.tilgangstype, q2.tilgangstype) 'Reception Type'
       ,ISNULL(q1.tilgangsnr, q2.tilgangsnr) 'Reception No'
       ,ISNULL(q1.dato, q2.dato) dato
       ,ISNULL(q1.LevNr, q2.LevNr) LevNr
       ,ISNULL(q1.Pakkemerke, q2.Pakkemerke) Pakkemerke
       ,ISNULL(q1.VareANr, q2.VareANr) VareANr
       ,ISNULL(q1.Ankomstdato,q2.Ankomstdato) 'Arrival Date'
       ,q1.Antall1
       ,q1.totkvant1
       ,q1.Antall2
       ,q1.totkvant2
       ,q2.Antall
       ,q2.totkvant
       ,q2.AntallTilFrys
       ,q2.TotKvantTilFrys
       ,ISNULL(q1.EksternKommentar1,q2.EksternKommentar1) EksternKommentar1
       ,q2.[Last Upsert]
FROM (
       SELECT w700.accountid
              ,w700.klientnr
              ,w700.tilgangstype
              ,w700.tilgangsnr
              ,w700.dato
              ,w700.Ankomstdato
              ,w700.LevNr
              ,w700.pakkemerke
              ,w789.VareANr
              ,sum(IIF(w789.prognosetype = 1, w789.Antall, NULL)) AS Antall1
              ,sum(IIF(w789.prognosetype = 1, w789.totkvant, NULL)) AS totkvant1
              ,sum(IIF(w789.prognosetype = 2, w789.Antall, NULL)) AS Antall2
              ,sum(IIF(w789.prognosetype = 2, w789.totkvant, NULL)) AS totkvant2
              ,w700.EksternKommentar1
       FROM trading.W789Prognosekjopstat AS w789
       INNER JOIN trading.W700Tilgangshode AS w700 ON w700.AccountId = w789.AccountId
              AND w700.KlientNr = w789.Klientnr
              AND w700.Tilgangsnr = w789.Tilgangsnr
              AND w700.Tilgangstype = w789.Tilgangstype
              AND w700.IsDeleted = 0
       WHERE w789.IsDeleted = 0
       GROUP BY w700.accountid
              ,w700.klientnr
              ,w700.tilgangstype
              ,w700.tilgangsnr
              ,w700.dato
              ,w700.Ankomstdato
              ,w700.LevNr
              ,w700.pakkemerke
              ,w789.VareANr
              ,w700.EksternKommentar1
       ) q1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
       SELECT w700.accountid
              ,w700.klientnr
              ,w700.tilgangstype
              ,w700.tilgangsnr
              ,w700.dato
              ,w700.Ankomstdato
              ,w700.LevNr
              ,w700.pakkemerke
              ,w702.VareANr
              ,w702.Antall
              ,w702.TotKvant
              ,w702.ValPris
              ,w702.AntallTilFrys
              ,w702.TotKvantTilFrys
              ,w700.EksternKommentar1
              ,(SELECT MAX(LastUpdateDate) FROM (VALUES (w702.createdAt),(w702.updatedAt)) AS UpdateDate(LastUpdateDate)) AS 'Last Upsert' 
       FROM trading.w702PrognoseKjop w702
       INNER JOIN trading.W700Tilgangshode AS w700 ON w700.AccountId = w702.AccountId
              AND w700.KlientNr = w702.Klientnr
              AND w700.Tilgangsnr = w702.Tilgangsnr
              AND w700.Tilgangstype = w702.Tilgangstype
              AND w700.IsDeleted = 0
       WHERE w702.IsDeleted = 0
       ) q2 ON q1.accountid = q2.accountid
       AND q1.klientnr = q2.klientnr
       AND q1.tilgangstype = q2.tilgangstype
       AND q1.tilgangsnr = q2.tilgangsnr
       AND q1.vareanr = q2.vareanr
WHERE totkvant1 IS NOT NULL
       OR totkvant2 IS NOT NULL
       OR totkvant IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering with `full join` is really tricky.  Your `where` criteria are actually turning the `full join` into a `left join`.

You can do what you want by filtering *before* the `join`:

```
select a.klientnr, a.uttakstype, a.uttaksnr, a.vareanr a.tableAitem,
       b.vareanr b.tableBitem, a.kvantum a.tableAquantity, b.totkvant b.tableBquantity 
from (select a.*
      from tableA a
      where a.UttaksNr = 639779 and a.IsDeleted = 0
     ) a full join
     (select b.*
      from tableB b
      where b.IsDeleted = 0
     ) b
     on a.klientnr = b.klientnr and
        a.uttakstype= b.uttakstype and 
        a.uttaksnr = b.uttaksnr and
        a.vareanr = b.vareanr;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon! I have to try this out in the more complex sql query i have going on! I'll come back with feedback as soon as i have tried it out!

Comment: and if there's more joins involved there, then I should take these joins in each subselect?

Comment: @LuizaOancea . . . Your question clearly refers to two *tables*.  You can replace these with more complicated expressions or use CTEs.  If it is not clear how to do this, then ask a new question with a more appropriate description of the issue.

Comment: I have edited the question to include a sql query where the full outer join works. Is this the correct way to handle this?